# SVM in RStudio cannot predict input from the user

Tags: r, svm

I have created a SVM in R and it runs successfully when I predict one of the rows from the original dataset

Example:
Let's say I use the first row of dataset

[image]

```
model <- readRDS("prediction_model.rds")
result <- predict(model, data[1,])
print(result)
```

The result is as below:

```
                 4 
Overweight_Level_I 
Levels: Insufficient_Weight Normal_Weight Obesity_Type_I Obesity_Type_II Obesity_Type_III Overweight_Level_I Overweight_Level_II
```

However, if I take the input from the user (Let's say I create a Shiny app and accept the user input)

```
user_input <- data.frame(Gender="Male", Age=20, Height=1.6, Weight=60, 
                     family_history_with_overweight="yes", FAVC="yes",
                     FCVC=1, NCP=1, CAEC="no", SMOKE="yes", CH2O=3, 
                     SCC="yes", FAF=0, TUE=2, CALC="no", MTRANS="Automobile")
```

And run the same code

```
model <- readRDS("prediction_model.rds")
result <- predict(model, user_input)
```

It will give me this error

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

I guess the error is caused by the dataframe that accepts users' input only having 1 unique value for each column. Hence, is there anyway to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

When you build your `user_input` you need to specify the number of levels of the factor columns.

For example, I've modified your code to add the levels for `Gender`:

```
user_input <- data.frame(Gender=factor("Male",levels=c("Female","Male")), Age=20, Height=1.6, Weight=60, 
                             family_history_with_overweight="yes", FAVC="yes",
                             FCVC=1, NCP=1, CAEC="no", SMOKE="yes", CH2O=3, 
                             SCC="yes", FAF=0, TUE=2, CALC="no", MTRANS="Automobile")
```

Check the structure of your original `data` e.g. using `str(data)` then make sure your `user_input` matches it, with all the levels of any factor specified in the correct order.